# Searching unanswered questions with certain tags not working?

Tags: bug, search, unanswered-questions

If I do a search like this: `answers:0 [java] -[android]` by typing it into the search box, I get expected results, like below:
[image: Find unanswered questions using the search box only]

However, if I first do a search using the tags `[java] -[android]`, and then click the Unanswered tab as below:

[image]

then I get no search results at all:

[image]

This is the URL: https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/java+-android

Am I missing something here?

Comment: can't confirm since I am on the new home page

Comment: @SagarV You can get back the old tabs in SO by [uncheck the options in the **New Question Filter**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRkc6.png) section under **Preferences** menu in the **Edit Profile & Settings**.